# Is this valid to put in a function so it waits for an opportunity to lock a mutex?

Tags: c++

As a primer, I am new to C++ threading.
Suppose the following code:

```
unique_lock <shared_mutex> lock(someSharedMutex);

if (!lock.owns_lock()) {
    while (!lock.try_lock()) {}
}
// Modify data
```

It looks really nasty but it seems like it would work. For context, I am making an OpenGL wrapper and am trying to thread the drawing. The VAOs are stored in a vector. The draw function obtains a shared lock over the mutex, and this lock would go in the code to add a VAO to the vector, as well as remove one.

Comment: Are you sure you need `shared_mutex` and not just plain old `mutex`? Are you sure you need a `unique_lock` and not just a `lock_guard`?

Comment: I would like multiple readers to access the data, in addition, they provide the owns_lock and try_lock functions.

Comment: The `unique_lock` constructor you're calling will lock the mutex, so your `if` statement will never be entered.

Comment: What if the mutex is already locked when the unique_lock tries to lock it?

Comment: In that case, the behavior is undefined unless the mutex is recursive. So you'd need to make sure you've done something like `someSharedMutex.lock_shared()`.

Comment: These questions can be easily answered by reading [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread). If the current thread owns the lock on the mutex, trying to lock it again is undefined behavior. If another thread has locked it, the `unique_lock` constructor will block until it acquires lock.

Comment: @bnaecker `lock_shared` won't help, it's still undefined behavior if called again from the same thread. As you said, you need a `recursive_mutex` for that.

Comment: @Praetorian Indeed. I was looking at the docs for both and got my wires crossed, thanks.

Comment: @Praetorian Thanks for the help. Think I got it figured out.